# Sequelize ORM Three Table One-to-Many Join?

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, sequelize.js

I may have erroneously phrased my post title.
I have Table A, whose PK: "id" is the FK of a composite primary in Table B. Table A also holds the Composite PK id of records in Table C as a FK. I need help writing a Sequelize query that finds the Table A ID who matches many records in Table B and has the Table C FK that points to another set of many records to be matched.

So far I have:

```js
TableA.findAll({
  attributes: ["id"],
  where: {
    include: [
      {
        model: "TableB",
        where: {
          TableA_id: {$col: "TableA.id"}   // Need all records that share this      
        }
      },
      {
        model: "TableC",
        where: {
          TableC_value: [4, 5, 6], //I need the record where these all share the same key
          TableC_PK: {$col: TableA.TableC_FK} 
       }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

I haven't tested this yet but I also don't know if I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Sequlize does not support composite primary and foreign keys so you need to indicate one field in associations and always use `on` option in `include` (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70677247/1376618)