# How to add AND condition when use inner join on Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have some sql code like this

```
select *
from people_work_attendances pwa
inner join people_work_placements pwp on pwa.user_work_id = pwp.id
inner join company_job_profile_r_attendance cjpa on pwp.job_profile = cjpa.profile and pwa.policy_id=cjpa.policy
WHERE
pwa.user_work_id = 71072
and cjpa.profile IS NOT NULL
```

i want to implement this section to Sequelize

```
inner join company_job_profile_r_attendance cjpa on pwp.job_profile = cjpa.profile and pwa.policy_id=cjpa.policy
```

current situation is i can make it like this

```
if(!module.exports.Placement.associations.JobProfileAttendance){
    module.exports.Placement.hasOne(module.exports.JobProfileAttendance, {
        as:'JobProfileAttendance',
        sourceKey:'jobProfile',
        foreignKey:'profile'
    })
}
```

but the result of this part is like this

```
INNER JOIN "public"."company_job_profile_r_attendance" AS "Placement->JobProfileAttendance" ON "Placement"."job_profile" = "Placement->JobProfileAttendance"."profile"
```

i want to make like this

```
INNER JOIN "public"."company_job_profile_r_attendance" AS "Placement->JobProfileAttendance" 
    ON "Placement"."job_profile" = "Placement->JobProfileAttendance"."profile" 
    AND "PeopleWorkAttendance"."policy_id" = "Placement->JobProfileAttendance"."policy"
```

want to add some AND conditions but in Sequelize

```
AND "PeopleWorkAttendance"."policy_id" = "Placement->JobProfileAttendance"."policy"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` option in `include`, just keep in mind that you always should do it manually because Sequelize doesn't support composite primary and foreign keys.
See `options.include[].on` in [findAll](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-findAll) options